# How do I get flyspell to ignore pandoc citations in markdown

Tags: flyspell, markdown, markdown-mode, pandoc

`Flyspell` regularly shows `pandoc` citations as a spelling error in `markdown` documents. For example `@chu2017` will come up as a spelling error for 'chu'.

How can I get `Flyspell` ignore the citations and only check other words in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `init.el`:

```
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (setq flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate 'my-pandoc-flyspell-verify)))

(defun my-pandoc-flyspell-verify ()
  (save-excursion
    (forward-word -1)
    (not (looking-back "@"))))
```

Essentially, it is telling `flyspell` not to check words that start with "@".

Comment: Awesome, thanks @scaramouche, that does the trick!